# 00000/Console.Clear() command on a Console application developed on windows 7 doesn't work properly in windows 11

Tags: c#, windows-7, console-application, desktop-application, windows-11

2 consoles applicatipns I developed in windows 7 (in Visual Studio 2015 community) in 2017
stil work properly on my old windows 7 computer but not on my windows 11 computer.

Problem on Windows 11 is that when I open the consoles, sometimes when the code reaches Console.Clear() command, it sometimes don't clear the entire console but only part of it.

(The consoles are text-based, so the consoles is supposed to always display some text on it and the Console.Clear() command is supposed to remove all the text currently displayed in the, but instead it only removes part of it sometimes).

The 2 consoles were programmed with C Sharp.

I'm not sure what more details I need to give to solve the problem, I'd be glad if you can direct me what information is needed to solve this problem..

Are consoles on windows 11 supposed to run differently on it than on windows 7?

What I expect is for the console to work the same in Windows 11 and remove all the text displayed in the console when it reaches the Console.Clear() command.

I tried:

1. I tried to run it on my windows 7 computer, it's works perfectly there.
2. I opened the consoles's soultions in a later DEV (visual studio community 2022),
   where I think I had to upgrade the project's code to the latest .NET framework (4.8, while the consoles were developed with .NET framework 4.5.2),
   because [Microsoft only offer to install .NET framework 4.6 and later versions.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk)

Can that be the root of the problem? Do I must install the old .NET framework 4.5.2 on my windows 11 computer for the consoles to work properly?
And if so how do I get and install that .NET framework?

3. I tried to add more Console.Clear() commands in the console's code, to every function, to ensure every function that writes and displays text on the console clears it right after every input (Console.ReadLine()) it receives.
   It didn't help at all.
4. Also I debugged the software, and as I thought when the Console.Clear() is run, it only clears part of the console at that specific line.
5. Can I run on the console on compatibility mode windows 7? There's that feature that allows you to run exe files so that they can be run with the operating system they were developed in?
6. Can the console buffer have something to do with this? Because it says in visual studio that Console.Clear() "clears the console buffer".

Also I tried changing the buffer size and it seemed to make a difference, but not solve the problem. Any idea why?

7. It also seems to depend on if a file that the console opened before the Console.Clear() command was opened or not because I never close the text files it opens, any idea why?

Edit: Ok everyone, I discovered there's something called an "escape sequence" (I have yet to understand what does that mean) that can be used like a password to clear the entire console by cleaning the scrollback buffer or something: Console.WriteLine("\x1b[3J"); I have yet to test if that's enough to solve my problem (it'll take time to ensure it works). If you guys can explain to me what does that mean and if it works, how does it work. If it works, it's probably like a password to return the scrollbar to its default state or something

Comment: "I'm not sure what more details I need to give to solve the problem." Write a simple program that prints some text and then calls `Console.Clear()`. Does that program have the same problem as your program? If so, then post that simple program. If not, then gradually make the simple program look more like your program until the problem occurs.

Comment: I see. It doesn't have the same problem (although the earliest .NET visual studio allows me to create the new console is 6.0, maybe it makes a difference). Anyway I'll update if I notice a difference.

Comment: @RaymondChen Based on all tests I've done, it seems that difference that in windows 11, the console.Clear() method only clears the text in the in the visiable text from the upside of the console windows (so that all text that requires scrolling down to see will NOT be cleared).

I'll try to fix my consoles with this. Anyway do you have any idea why would the Console.Clear() work so poorly on windows 11?

Comment: Oh no I got confused.. It's the opposite: the part that Console.Clear() doesn't delete is the part that requires scrolling UP to see, not down.

Anyway I'm thinking it may have something to do with the buffer area..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community The specific problem is clear enough, isn't it? The command Console.Clear() doesn't work.
As for detail, I'm researching what are the relevant details excatly for this purpose.
I just figured out I can set the buffer side for the entire window, which cleans properly for the most part but creates giant unneccesary space, and doesn't clean text from files.. weird.

Comment: Ok everyone, I discovered there's something called an "escape sequence" (I have yet to understand what does that mean) that can be used like a password to clear the entire console by cleaning the scrollback buffer or something:

Console.WriteLine("\x1b[3J");

I have yet to test if that's enough to solve my problem (it'll take time to ensure it works).

If you guys can explain to me what does that mean and if it works, how does it work. If it works, it's probably like a password to return the scrollbar to its default state or something.